# How to specify index and date / time field in Timelion?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

I'm trying to use the Timelion app in Kibana, but I don't find where to specify the index name and the time field. Is there a way to do that on-the-fly or does it have to be done in a configuration file somewhere? If so, where is that file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
.es(index=your_index_name, timefield=@timestamp, metric=count, q=whatever_field:some_matching_text)
```

Under the `es()` function you have `index` and `timefield`.